# Going back from screen in stacknaviagtion to screen in drawernavigation is not working react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have two navigator in my application.

**Stack Navigation:**

```
const MainStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    MainScreen: { screen: Home },
    ProductDetail: { screen: ProductDetail },
    Search: { screen: Search },
    Shop: { screen: Shop },
},{
    headerMode: 'none',
});
```

**Drawer Navigation:**

```
const MainDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: MainStackNavigator,
    },
    Wishlist: {
        screen: Wishlist,
    },
    Login: {
        screen: Login,
    },
    Register: {
        screen: Register,
    },
    Logout: {
        screen: Logout,
    },
})
```

The problem is When I'm in my **Wishlist Screen** I've my product card onPress of that I'm navigating to the **ProductDetail Screen** but when I press back button I'm redirecting to the `MainScreen` of the app.

I want that if I have came from wishlist screen on going back it should be go to wishlist screen.

Answer (score 0):

You must attach your `MainStackNavigator` to `Wishlist`, not to `Home`